# Chart corrupt when load listboxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts, listbox

I've weird problem , I'm a beginner making small program Solves some statistics using listboxes and displaying 2 charts
the problem is that when I try to save the first 3 main listboxes to a txt file and load it again and making the same process before saving every thing going right Except one chart that has stepline Painted right but zooming in X axis is not the same befor saving, and there is another crossing lines painted according to points in the Stepline it painted in a different wrong place from before saving

Even if i enter specific X,Y values for the crossing lines it's don't look the same befor saving

this is the code for the save button

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim w As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim strFilename As String
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "Table"
    SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Table"
    SaveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = True
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        strFilename = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        w = New IO.StreamWriter(strFilename)
        For i = 0 To lstFrom.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(lstFrom.Items.Item(i))
        Next
        w.WriteLine("*")
        For i = 0 To lstFrom.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(lstTo.Items.Item(i))
        Next
        w.WriteLine("**")
        For i = 0 To lstFrom.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(lstF.Items.Item(i))
        Next
        w.Close()
    End If
```

this is the code for open button

```
    ClearAll()
    Dim strFileName As String
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        .Title = "Open Table"
    End With
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim myreader As New StreamReader(strFileName)
        Dim line As String
        line = myreader.ReadLine()
        Do Until line = "*"
            lstFrom.Items.Add(line)
            line = myreader.ReadLine()
        Loop
        Do Until line = "**"
            lstTo.Items.Add(line)
            line = myreader.ReadLine()
        Loop
        Do Until line = ""
            lstF.Items.Add(line)
            line = myreader.ReadLine()
        Loop
        myreader.Close()
        lstTo.Items.Remove(lstTo.Items(0)) ' that's remove the "*"
        lstF.Items.Remove(lstF.Items(0)) ' That's remove the "**"
        AllWork()
    End If
```

AllWork() is the same method That make the whole process and displaying charts

This is All the code that redrwing the corrupted chart in open button

This is from ClearAll() method

```
    Chart2.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(1).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(2).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(3).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(4).Points.Clear()
```

This is in the AllWork() method

```
    Chart2.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(1).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(2).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(3).Points.Clear()
    Chart2.Series(4).Points.Clear()

             For i = 0 To lstVariableFrequency.Items.Count - 1
                If lstVariableFrequency.Items(i) = dblHighestVariableFrequency Then
                    dblF1 = lstVariableFrequency.Items(i - 1)
                    dblF2 = lstVariableFrequency.Items(i + 1)
                    dblClassBoundry2 = lstTo.Items(i) - lstFrom.Items(i)
                    dblVersusF = lstFrom.Items(i)




                    Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i - 1), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i - 1))
                    Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i))
                    Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i + 1), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i + 1))

                    Chart2.Series(1).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i - 1))
                    Chart2.Series(1).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i + 1), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i))

                    Chart2.Series(2).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i))
                    Chart2.Series(2).Points.AddXY(lstFrom.Items(i + 1), lstVariableFrequency.Items(i + 1))

                    dblMode = dblVersusF + (dblF2 / (dblF1 + dblF2)) * dblClassBoundry2
                    Exit For
                End If
```

Setting the lstfrom list that represent the x axes in the chart in the open button

```
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim myreader As New StreamReader(strFileName)
    Dim line As String
    line = myreader.ReadLine()
    Do Until line = "*"
        lstFrom.Items.Add(line)
        line = myreader.ReadLine()
    Loop
```

this code sets lstVariableFrequency list that represent the Y axes

```
        For i = 0 To lstFrom.Items.Count - 1
            lstL.Items.Add(lstTo.Items(i) - lstFrom.Items(i))
            lstVariableFrequency.Items.Add(lstF.Items(i) / lstL.Items(i))
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I Solved the problem it was trivial Thing !!! I don't believe it
All the problem that the Code that draws the chart must have convert Function like this

```
Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(CDbl(lstFrom.Items(i - 1)), CDbl(lstVariableFrequency.Items(i - 1)))
```

Thanks for any one have read my question and tried to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your open code to the below

```
ClearAll()
Dim strFileName As String
With OpenFileDialog1
    .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    .Title = "Open Table"
End With
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim myreader As New StreamReader(strFileName)
    Dim line As String
    Do Until line = "*"
        line = myreader.ReadLine()
        If line <> "*" Then
            lstFrom.Items.Add(line)
            line = myreader.ReadLine()
        End If
    Loop
    Do Until line = "**"
        line = myreader.ReadLine()
        If line <> "**" Then
            lstTo.Items.Add(line)
            line = myreader.ReadLine()
        End If
    Loop
    Do Until line = ""
        lstF.Items.Add(line)
        line = myreader.ReadLine()
    Loop
    myreader.Close()
    AllWork()
End If
```

It looks like the separators (* and/or **) you are using are getting confused into the data?

Comment: I tried this code but it corrupted the arrangement of the listboxes and Added the "**" to the last listbox
This images illustrates what happens in my code
that's before saving
https://thumbs.rapidshare.com/thumbs/1024/326/7C9FD4F756F83853EC53023A9260A.jpg
That's after loading the saved listboxes from the txt file
https://thumbs.rapidshare.com/thumbs/1024/010/5B1CB88BFB5115CD693D22DF41AE2.jpg

Comment: Looking at your CHARTS the information looks correct EXCEPT for the RED LINE The main difference as you stated is the SCALING so that would lead one to assume that your scaling is DEFAULTING? to a preset setting? does that sound right to you? because if you look at where the LINES START/FINISH the values are CORRECT but the scaling is different in your TWO PICS so.... Are they ACTUALLY using a different scaling setting? check your code that redraws the chart, post it even... in case anyone may spot something that has been overlooked.